# Can I use rich text in Nativescript labels or Textviews

Tags: android, ios, nativescript

I am building an application that contain a lot of text that need to be formatted with :
Underlines
Bold
Web Links
Strike trough
etc, ...
I know that I can apply this formatting to the complete text but did not find a way to do so on specific sentences or words in the text.
Is there any type of enrich the text (Like for example markdown) that would allow me to add this formatting.

Important note, I would like to add this formatting in native elements and not open a webview and inject HTML markup.

Ideally the solution should be platform agnostic, support both IOS and Android and any future target integrated in NativeScript in the future.

Thanks

Raymond

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - you can use the HTMLView component. *Please note that this is NOT using a browser, but renders native rich text components.*

for more info please check the docs - http://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/ui/html-view/HOW-TO

Comment: Thanks Valentine,I did not realise that HTMLView could be used as a component and assumed that it was a view covering all the screen (Like a page). In fact after reading your answer I managed to use the HTMLView Component in Stacks and columns with enough precision. Pity that this capability is not built in Labels, buttons and all components with a text element.

Answer (score 0):

As of now I believe this can be done using Native script [FormattedString](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/formatted-string).

It should work on both Android and iOS. Below is a quick sample of the Nativescript component usage:

```
<Label class="h3 p-15 m-15 text-left">
    <FormattedString>
        <Span text="Words " color="#006600" ></Span>
        <Span text="with " color="#990000" fontAttributes="Bold"></Span>
        <Span text="different " color="#ffcc00"></Span>
        <Span text="color."></Span>
    </FormattedString>
</Label>
```

You can use the supported CSS to style your text accordingly. For example to udnerline text you can use css property **text-decoration: underline;**